# Why doesn't this FQL return profile pictures for some users?

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

This FQL is from an app which has been running for a few days now, and has been thoroughly tested:

```
SELECT src_big FROM photo WHERE aid IN (SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner = {uid} AND type = 'profile')
```

I'm using the JS API bridged from ActionScript and the `{uid}` part is replaced with whatever uid corresponds to a list item clicked in a friend browser. The thing is that most of the time this query works fine and nice, large images are returned (although usually not a complete set of matching profile images), but in some instances the query does not return anything at all, just an empty array. Checking the user's profile images album confirms that there are plenty of images to choose from. Anyone know why that might be?

Answer (score 1):

Probably because that user has their privacy settings set so you cannot access their profile picture.

Comment: Yeah, that was my first guess as well, but then I thought about this: When a user logs in through my application, granting the necessary permissions to load his friends' photos, the application is acting on that user's behalf. Effectively operating on the same access level as the logged in user. If this user has access to a friend's profile pictures, then it does not make sens that these pictures are visible to the user on facebook.com and not when accessing them through the app.

Comment: And where would that privacy setting be by the way? I tried going through my own settings to see if there was anything that would let me deny API access, but nothing really gave itself away.

Comment: In Privacy settings (http://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=privacy), Apps and Websites link at the bottom left. The "Info accessible through your friends" section. Just because they can see it doesn't mean your app can.

Comment: The application does not act on the user's behalf unless you are presenting a dialog, like posting to a friend's wall. A user can post to a friend's wall, but an app can't without presenting a confirmation dialog.

Answer (score 1):

That's because some fields are visible to public and others need permissions, if you navigate to the [`users.getInfo`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/users.getInfo/) method as advised from the [`user`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/) table. You'll find the list of *public* fields that you can query for any user:

- uid
- first_name
- middle_name
- last_name
- name
- locale
- current_location
- affiliations (regional type only)
- pic_square
- profile_url
- sex

Now query the `album` table would most likely return nothing if the user didn't grant you permissions, but it's worth to try the following:

```
SELECT pic_big FROM user WHERE uid={uid}
```

If it didn't work then you may need to stick with `pic_square` from the list above.

Also it's worth to note that all the `pic` fields might be empty:

> **pic_big** The URL to the largest-sized
>   profile picture for the user being
>   queried. The image can have a maximum
>   width of 200px and a maximum height of
>   600px. **This URL may be blank**.

This applies to all the pics as mentioned in the `user` table.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:**
It's always a good practice to have a fallback image (a generic image) to use whenever no image is returned!